# Cannot run Errai Dev Mode with JBoss AS or Wildfly

Tags: java, gwt, jboss, wildfly, errai

I'm trying to use Errai 3 new features which is JBoss AS integration, however I am getting this error:

> [ERROR] Unable to load server class
>   'org.jboss.errai.cdi.server.gwt.JBossLauncher' [ERROR]
>   java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
>   org.jboss.errai.cdi.server.gwt.JBossLauncher [ERROR]  at
>   java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366) [ERROR]    at
>   java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355) [ERROR]    at
>   java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) [ERROR]    at
>   java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354) [ERROR]    at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425) [ERROR]     at
>   sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308) [ERROR]
>     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358) [ERROR]    at
>   java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method) [ERROR]   at
>   java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:270) [ERROR]   at
>   com.google.gwt.dev.DevMode$ArgHandlerServer.setString(DevMode.java:118)
>   [ERROR]   at
>   com.google.gwt.util.tools.ArgHandlerString.handle(ArgHandlerString.java:26)
>   [ERROR]   at
>   com.google.gwt.util.tools.ToolBase.processArgs(ToolBase.java:238)
>   [ERROR]   at
>   com.google.gwt.dev.ArgProcessorBase.processArgs(ArgProcessorBase.java:29)
>   [ERROR]   at com.google.gwt.dev.DevMode.main(DevMode.java:310)

The POM configuration is this:

```
<configuration>
   <logLevel>WARN</logLevel>
   <runTarget>App.html</runTarget>
   <!--<extraJvmArgs>-Xmx1500m -XX:MaxPermSize=1000m -XX:-UseSplitVerifier</extraJvmArgs>-->
   <extraJvmArgs>-Xmx1500m -XX:CompileThreshold=7000 -XX:MaxPermSize=1000m -Derrai.jboss.home=${errai.jboss.home} -Derrai.jboss.javaagent.path=${settings.localRepository}/org/jboss/errai/errai-client-local-class-hider/${errai.devmode.version}/errai-client-local-class-hider-${errai.devmode.version}.jar</extraJvmArgs>
   <!--<soyc>false</soyc>-->
   <hostedWebapp>src/main/webapp</hostedWebapp>
   <!--<server>org.jboss.errai.cdi.server.gwt.JettyLauncher</server>-->
   <compileSourcesArtifacts>
      <compileSourcesArtifact>org.drools:guvnor-api</compileSourcesArtifact>
      <compileSourcesArtifact>org.drools:droolsjbpm-ide-common</compileSourcesArtifact>
      <compileSourcesArtifact>com.mycompany:models</compileSourcesArtifact>
   </compileSourcesArtifacts>
   <noServer>false</noServer>
   <server>org.jboss.errai.cdi.server.gwt.JBossLauncher</server>
   <disableCastChecking>true</disableCastChecking>
   <runTarget>webapp/App.html</runTarget>
   <!-- The GWT compiler must the correct JDT version -->
   <!-- drools-compiler has dependency on org.eclipse.jdt.core.compiler:ecj:jar:3.5.1:compile -->
   <gwtSdkFirstInClasspath>true</gwtSdkFirstInClasspath>
   <draftCompile>false</draftCompile>
</configuration>
```

What could be missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add this in your pom.xml

```
<dependency>  
 <groupId>org.jboss.errai</groupId>  
 <artifactId>errai-cdi-jboss</artifactId>  
 <version>${errai.version}</version>  
</dependency>
```